# What can I do if I still do not understand an interaction from a DCI online test?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The instruction pages for the online [DCI Judges exams/practice tests](http://judge.wizards.com/exams.aspx) (requires login) says:

> Before you start, it's important to note that, in order for the testing experience to remain relevant and give everyone a good gauge of their knowledge **you may not disclose any of the content on any of the tests, anywhere.**

If this is the case what should I do if there was a question/interaction I did not understand even after the explanation given?

Comment: You could have asked the question without mentioning it was on the test, but it's kinda late for that now

Comment: @ikegami I suppose I could have presented it as a play situation without any context, but I still would have felt I was violating the test as that exact question's answer would then be available from google.

Comment: It's what the Rules Q&A board at Wizard was recommending. Changing it up as much as possible is good, of course.

Comment: @Fr33dan You could just make up an equivalent play scenario that has the same issue and then ask about that.

Comment: If you want, you can email the question to me (ikegami@adaelis.com). I've already passed the RA test, and I won't take the Judges one. (DCI can't send emails to my email address, and I don't play anymore anyway.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to ask questions about a game pursuant to a particular non-disclosure agreement, not about a game.

Comment: To clarify my close reason, your question isn't really about Magic. It's more about interpreting an implied contract you have with the DCI regarding non-disclosure of content on their website. That's not what this site is for.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I considered it could be interpreted that way but I consider the tests an extension of the game, and thus asking about the rules of the test is tantamount to asking about the rules of the game. Maybe that's too much of a leap though.

Comment: @ikegami I will probably just come up with another way to demonstrate the same concept with different cards as murgatoid99 suggests, but thank you.

Comment: There should be a feedback form for the test that you can use to ask for further clarification on specific questions.

Comment: I think this question is reasonable and on topic. MTG players can answer this better than anyone else, even if it isn't a question about the MTG game itself. See http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/1167/5573

Answer (score 1):

You probably have some sort of judge-mentor, which is either a higher Level judge that might eventually take your judge-test or your regional coordinator.

If there was a question or interaction that you did not understand after the explanation, you can talk with this mentor in private about it.